# JSX: How to create a css-class using 2 string and css modules

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx, css-modules

I'm using `CSS Modules` in my `React` app. There is a need to set a class that will consist of 2 strings and then converted to module.

Example.

```
import React from 'react';
import css from './ContentMedia.module.css';

const Content = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className={css.container}>
           {props.areas && 
               props.areas.map((area) => {
                   return (
                       <div className={`css.areaGrid${area.grid}`} key={area.id}>
                          ...
                       </div>
                   );
               });
           }
        </div>
    );
};

export default Content;
```

If I'm setting class as `className={css.areaGrid${area.grid}}` I receive the wrong result (see the picture below). But I need to receive a predefined css-class `.areaGrid12` or `.areaGrid6` or `.areaGrid4` that should look like i.e. `Content_areaGrid12_6yth`. How should I fix the JSX to make it work?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is the following:

```
<div className={`${css.areaGrid}${area.grid}`} key={area.id}>
   {/* your implementation */}
</div>
```

Think about the following:

```js
const css = { areaGrid: 'area' };
const area = { grid: 'else' };

console.log(`${css.areaGrid}${area.grid}`);
```

Or if you have a list of properties in `css` variable - obviously the values in your case are different:

```js
const area = { grid: '12' };
const css = {
  areaGrid12: 'twelve',
  areaGrid6: 'six',
  areaGrid4: 'four'
};

const result = `${css[`areaGrid${area.grid}`]}`;

console.log(result);
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thx bro, but this is not what I 'm looking for ...

Comment: Be careful of the spacing though, depending if you want `areaelse` or `area else`. Though it looks like OP wants ``className={css[`areaGrid${area.grid}`]}``

Comment: @EmileBergeron Thanks for pointing that out. Just extended the answer with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

This one is what I was looking for .... Thank you **Emile Bergeron**!!!

`` className={css[`areaGrid${area.grid}`]} ``

Answer (score 0):

It works if to do this:

```
let cssClass = '';

if (area.grid === '12') {
    cssClass = css.areaGrid12;
} else if (area.grid === '6') {
    cssClass = css.areaGrid6;
} else if (area.grid === '4') {
    cssClass = css.areaGrid4;
}

<div className={cssClass}> .....
```

But this solution IMHO is not very flexible ;)

Comment: Or just ``className={css[`areaGrid${area.grid}`]}``